# Python DES libraries

Tags: python, des

I am just wondering if there are any Python libraries out there that can help me implement DES. Maybe ones that can generate the sub keys or apply permutations.

Thanks.

Comment: DES is pretty much broken, so hopefully your only trying that for educational purpose?

Comment: Yes this is totally for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The [`pycrypto` library](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) is the de-facto encryption library for python.  It supports encryption and decryption of DES blocks, however DES only supports passwords of 7 bytes in length, and is considered obsolete and insecure. You're better off using a newer encryption standard like AES.

Comment: Hi, It needs to be DES encryption. As you said the pycrypto library only supports simplified DES.

Comment: `pycrypto` supports the full DES encryption algorithm. I never said it only supports simplified DES.